# Is it possible to write a number of 'div's in an html file with different id and selectively display them using an if-else statement in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a Python function that returns 1 out of 80 possible values and based on the value returned, I need to display different blocks of text. The functionality that I'm trying to achieve looks roughly like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>

        <div id="1"> One </div>
        <div id="2"> Two </div>
        <div id="3"> Three </div>

        {% if id == "1" %}
            display div with id "1"
        {% elif id == "2" %}
            display div with id "2"
        {% else %}
            display div with id "3"
        {% endif %}

    </body>
</html>
```

So, I want to write 80 differect 'div's somewhere in the html file and display them selectively based on the value returned by the Python function. Is this even possible to do? If not, what other alternatives do I have?

Edit - The divs are not just blocks of text. They contain html too.

Comment: Why exactly do you feel like you need to write 80 individual `div`s that all simply display text, and why is it that you don't rewrite your function to return a message instead of an arbitrary integer that needs to be mapped to a message? You're creating complications for yourself. Don't get mired in conditional logic. You'll write way more code than you need.

Comment: @Allie Fitter. It's not just text, there are a lot of html elements in it as well. To give you a little more info, the function returns the ICD-9 code of a disease. I then have to display information like symptoms, diagnosis, some images etc. pertaining to that particular disease which cannot be just done by returning a string.

Comment: Html is a string. That's all it is. Encoded text. One sec, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way will be to create items as a list of objects:

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'value': 'One'}, {'id':2, 'value': 'Two'}]
return render_template('hello.html', items=items)
```

And in your html template (Jinja2 is default for flask):

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item.id == 1 %}
    <div id="1">{{ item.value }}</div>
  {% elif item.id == 2 %}
    <div id="2">Second item</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But if all the divs are in html code and you want to show, hide them, then you will need javascript for that:

1. Add `display: none;` to the div style, they all will be hidden.
2. Let's say your python code will return item_id as an return value, we need to show that item (using jquery plugin):

Add in script tag:

```
var item = '{{ item_id }}';
$('#' + item).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon [Emin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3042057/emin-mastizada) answer, you could have a dictionary with the values returned from your function as keys and the string to display as the values. Then pass the dictionary and the result of the function.

### app.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    messages = {
        '1': """<div id="commonCold">
            <h2>Common Cold</h3>
            <h3>Symptoms</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Cough</li>
                <li>Sore Throat</li>
                <li>Congestion</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="commonCold.png"></img>
        </div>""", 
        '2': """<div id="influenza">
            <h2>Influenza</h3>
            <h3>Symptoms</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Cough</li>
                <li>Sore Throat</li>
                <li>Congestion</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="influenza.png"></img>
        </div>"""
    id = your_function()
    return render_template('index.html', id=id, messages=messages)
```

### index.html

```
<div id={{ id }}>{{ messages[id] }} </div>
```

Avoid conditional logic if at all possible. If not for yourself, then for the next person who touches your code. Trust me, refactoring it is arduous. You should cut out the middle man and just return a message from your function and then simply display that.

#### EDIT:

Updated the answer. Note that this still is not very good. Hard-coded data  like this requires code updated whenever there are changes. The correct approach would be to put all this into a database. And then pass the data to html and populate it with Jinja. In MySQL for instance:

```
"""SELECT `name`,
       img,
       symptoms
FROM diseases
WHERE id = {id}""".format(id=id)
```